# Moving files to with certain characters in their name to a different directory in IOS/linnux terminal

Tags: ios, bash, command-line

I have the following files in a directory

```
BH8_F1_2_S103_L006_R1_001.fastq.gz
BH8_F1_2_S103_L006_R2_001.fastq.gz
BH8_F1_2_S103_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz
BH8_F1_2_S103_L007_R2_001.fastq.gz
BH8_F1_2_S103_R1_001.fastq.gz
BH8_F1_2_S103_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I am trying to move the files with "L006" and "L007" in their name to a new directory i have created.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. Please delete and post in a more appropriate place such as [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It's often good to be as specific as you can while using wildcards:

```
mv *_L00[67]_* new_directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use

```
mv *L006* new_location
mv *L0007* new_location
```

where `new_location` is a directory/directory path.

Alternatively,

```
mv *L00[67]* new_location
```

to move both types of file at once.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: that's right, thank you. I couldn't remember the or off the top of my head. Edited!